# Answer no to all questions using the yes command

Tags: bash, rm

I'm trying to remove **all** files *except* read-only ones, but this command removes all of them anyway:

```sh
yes n | rm *
```

Did I do something wrong? If not, why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `rm` to automatically enable `-i` mode that prompts the user to delete unwritable files, the standard input has to be a terminal (as specified in the man pages).

So, for the command to work correctly the user has to specify the `-i` option manually:

```sh
yes n | rm -i *
```

After doing so the command works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In Posix systems, the read-only state of a file does not prevent it from being removed by `rm`.

You haven't said what your shell is, but perhaps you have an alias to `rm` that does ask you for confirmation when the file is read-only, and that alias behaves differently when it `stdin` is part of a pipe.

Comment: I'm using bash on Mint Ulyana and have no defined aliases, in fact `unalias` reports "not found". I even tried using /etc/bash.bashrc and repl.it but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you only need write permissions to the folder, not to the files, to remove them:

([From here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150108210426/http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/aunix1/filepermissions.htm))

> Any attempt to access a file's data requires read permission.  Any attempt to modify a file's data requires write permission.  Any attempt to execute a file (a program or a script) requires execute permission.
>
> In *nix systems directories are also files and thus use the same permission system as for regular files.  Note permissions assigned to a directory are not inherited by the files within that directory.
>
> Because directories are not used in the same way as regular files, the permissions work slightly (but only slightly) differently.  An attempt to list the files in a directory requires read permission for the directory, but not on the files within.  An attempt to add a file to a directory, delete a file from a directory, or to rename a file, all require write permission for the directory, but (perhaps surprisingly) not for the files within.  Execute permission doesn't apply to directories (a directory can't also be a program).  But that permission bit is reused for directories for other purposes.

To find files with specific permissions you can use

```
find -perm <mode>
```

[read more](https://ostechnix.com/find-files-based-permissions/)

To remove files found by find you can use

```
 find . -perm 444 -exec /bin/rm {} \;
```

(mybe slightly different, it depends on files you search and system you have)

[more exec examples](https://linuxaria.com/howto/linux-shell-how-to-use-the-exec-option-in-find-with-examples)